# Pages load in div, don't want to make a new page for home page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I use jQuery to load new pages inside of a div, but I don't want to make a page just for the content I have in that div on my home page. My script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".navigation").on("click", function(){  
            $("#content").load($(this).attr("page"));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everything loads fine in

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

but my navigation section is structured to have HOME be a selection.

```
<nav id="menu">
    <a href="" title="" page="home.php" class="navigation">Home</a>
    <a href="" title="" page="about.php" class="navigation">About</a>
</nav>
```

So is there a way to get the script to load whatever I have inside of the "content" div in my original page, or would it just be easier to make the "HOME" button be an actual link to the index page?

Everything still works if I change it to

```
<a href="index.php" title="">Home</a>
```

I just don't like the whole page loading as opposed to clicking on other buttons on the site and only having the content load.

Comment: UHm, why not just do `page="index.php"`? And BTW, use data attributes, don't make up your own invalid attributes.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's a way to do this without having to reload the entire page. Also, should I change it to data-page, then?

Comment: Yes, you should use `data-page`and yes, there is a way to do this without reloading the page, if the link is `home` you add a filter, see the documentation for jQuery's `load` on how to add a selector as a filter for the content etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll definitely read up more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments):

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document
>   that is fetched:
>
> $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );

So you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".navigation").on("click", function(){  
            var page = $(this).data("page");
            if(page == "index.php"){                    
                 //Load only element with id content from index.php
                 $("#content").load(page + " #content"); 
            } else{
                $("#content").load(page);
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<nav id="menu">
    <a href="" title="" data-page="index.php" class="navigation">Home</a>
    <a href="" title="" data-page="about.php" class="navigation">About</a>
</nav>
```

PS. You shouldn't use invalid attributes as pointed out by adeneo, so I changed yours to data attributes.

Comment: Yes, I added data-page to my links, and change the .attr to .data as well. This works great, but my content div's attributes from my CSS are also being loaded (into the content div, so double borders). I should be able to read up and figure the rest out on my own. Thanks a bunch for the solution!

And, I got it. Changed:

    $("#content").load(page + " #content"); 
to
    $("#content").load(page + " .alt-content"); 
so it loaded a different div from the same page. Thanks again!